# How do I get the bot to send embed message when a new video is posted?

Tags: youtube-api, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to use the YouTube API to get my discord bot to send me a message when I post a new video, but since I'm a beginner I do not know how to do this. The idea is that it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/j8je80 , the embed is ready but the api part of youtube is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to [subscribe to push notification](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications).

> The YouTube Data API (v3) supports push notifications via
>   [PubSubHubbub](https://github.com/pubsubhubbub/), a server-to-server publish/subscribe protocol for
>   Web-accessible resources. Notifications are pushed out to subscribers
>   via HTTP webhooks, which is much more efficient than polling-based
>   solutions. With PubSubHubbub, your server finds out about events in
>   near real-time, without having to determine the optimal polling
>   interval or repeatedly fetching data that hasn’t changed.

So these are the following activities that will trigger the push notification:

> - uploads a video
> - updates a video's title
> - updates a video's description

To be able to implement these, there is a step by step explanation on how to subscribe.